# Something strange with Project Paths in IntelliJ 14.1.4

Tags: intellij-idea, package

So, something has started to act weird in my intelliJ project.  I even tried removing the iml and .idea data, to no avail.

I go to Project Structure.  There, I have a content root.  Withing, I have three folders - one for my jar (and jni lib), one for Samples and one for Tools (just tools written to use the jar).  The jar, Samples and Tools are marked blue (sources).

In the jar folder, I have my source tree (com\company\projectname\XXX), a lib folder, a folder for my JNI lib and a folder I created call 'junit', which is the focus of this question.  It is marked in Project Structure in green (Tests).

Within, I have a folder structure eerily similar to my code: com\company\projectname\junit.

When I open a file in junit\com\company\xxx\junit, I have a big red underline under my `package com.company.xxx.junit;` line which tells me: "Package name 'com.company.xxx.junit' does not correspond to the file path 'junit.com.company.xxx.junit'.

I was under the impression that marking a folder as 'Tests' would instruct the IDE to use that as a "parent" folder, if you will, eliminating the need to prepend another folder name.

How can I separate the code from unit tests and in fact, create two junit test suites (one is for internal use, the other is a 'skeleton' for distribution), park them under one "umbrella" folder and NOT have to prepend the package names with that folder name?

**Update**: Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Your impression is correct. To understand what's happening here, could you please attach the screenshot of your Project Structure dialog?

Comment: @yole Added.  Doctored the names a bit, but the paths and depths are reflective of reality.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screen shot, the issue is that the `junit` directory is a subdirectory of another source directory, namely `MyProvider`. A source directory (whether a "production" source or a unit test source directory) cannot be a subdirectory of another source directory.

You need to either:

1. move the `junit` directory out of `MyProvider` so it is a sibling directory, or
2. unmark `MyProvider` as a source directory, create a `main` (or some such directory) in `MyProvider`, mark it as a source directory, and then move the `com` directory/package into `main`.

Option 2 would be the preferred way to deal with this as it follows a very common directory structure standard.

**UPDATE** (Following comment from OP)

Here's a couple of screenshot showing the configuration you desire:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I had tried it with MyProvider unmarked as a source root, no change.  I tried your suggestion: I created a MyProvider\src folder, marked it as a source root, then moved com.* under it.  All of the java files were refactored in the move to include 'src' leading the package name.  No change in the tests either.  Would this be a bug in IntelliJ - that source or test roots have their names added to package names if they are not at the content root level?

Comment: I doubt it is a bug. I consistently have my source and test roots in sub-directories (and thus not at the content root). And there would be a ton of traffic on the IntelliJ IDEA forums if this was happening. It sounds like IDEA just got a bit confused when you did the move, or there is still an issue in your configuration. You may want to consider closing IDEA, deleting the `.idea` directory, delete any `*.mil` files, and start from scratch in configuring the project. I also added some screenshots that might help.

Comment: I again removed the .idea folder and .iml file and recreated the project with no success. In fact, moving the com.* structure under a new folder named 'src' only exacerbates the problem - now those source files complain that the package name 'com.*' does not correspond to the file path 'src.com.*'. The only thing that seems to work, is to move the 'junit' folder one level up in the tree (so it's sitting in the content root) and mark it as a Test folder.

Comment: Further, I can only mark folders that are directly beneath the content root as source, test, etc, via the right-click 'Mark folder as' context menu option. If I go to project settings, I am able to mark any folder however I like. I am also using the community edition of IntelliJ.. would that make a difference? Tried latest EAP release, same issue.

Comment: @Jon - Below is a link to a zip file that has a project setup and configured as you are trying to do. I honestly think you are just not configuring something correctly. Open the sample project and compare to what you have. Note that you may get an error for the JDK if you do not have one defined with the same name ("1.8") as the one I used. Just change the SDK in the Project Structure if that happens. If after viewing the example project you are still having issues, we can try to move this to a chat. https://www.dropbox.com/s/thl2ihrvvyc4qhv/StackOverflow-31597450-Example.zip?dl=0

Comment: That sample does work.  So, I am really puzzled then, why my structure does not.  I've deleted all IntelliJ-generated files and dirs and tried to create a new project, or import a project.. both give me the same results.

Comment: I have been working with this for a bit now.  I recreated the project (per your structure above), I don't know how many times.  Even stripped it down to just src and junit dirs.  I got it eventually to import properly when working from a root level folder (c:\git\MyProvider).  When I moved that back to the git working dir (c:\git\projects), it would fail, unless I put it one level deeper, or renamed the content root folder. A bit more of trying to nail down what file in there could be borking things, led it to eventually open correctly .. no reason why. So, for now, today, it's working.  :-/

Comment: And today, it's back to not behaving correctly.  Is there someplace where the ide is making settings changes that I can look at for problems?  The inconsistency of behaviour is frustrating, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the .IdeaIC15 folder and started over. Working for now. Something must have gotten confused in the config, either as part of the update, or in the course of operation. I have taken a backup copy as it is now, so if this happens again, I will have something to check.